# group tuples directly and indirectly connected

Tags: python, list, tuples, grouping, graph-theory

I have a huge list of (x, y) tuples, with x and y positive integers. No tuples are equal. I want to group connected tuples.

1. The connection can be direct, as when (a, b) and (c, d) have a==c or b==d. So (a, b) and (c, d) will be grouped together.
2. The connection can also be indirect, as when (a, b), (c, d) and (e, f) have a!=e and b!=f, but a==c or b==d and c==e or d==f. Kind of a chain, with (c, d) being like a link between (a, b) and (e, f) that do not match directly. So (a, b), (c, d) and (e, f) will be grouped together.
3. The last case would be tuples disconnected. In this case, neither direct or indirect connection could be found. Each disconnected tuple will be on their own group.

Example of input and output with a small list:

```
IN = [(3, 9), (4, 6), (0, 9), (3, 8), (4, 8), (4, 7), (3, 6), (30, 97), (30, 88), (90, 40),]

# three groups as output
# first group made of six directly and indirectly connected tuples
# second group made of two directly connected tuples
# third group made of one disconnected tuple
OUT = [[(3, 9), (0, 9), (3, 8), (3, 6), (4, 6), (4, 8), (4, 7)],
 [(30, 97), (30, 88)],
 [(90, 40)]]
```

I've tried the following code:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

def group_tuples(tuples):
    tuples.sort(key=itemgetter(0, 1))
    
    groups = []
    for key, group in groupby(tuples, key=itemgetter(0)):
        groups.append(list(group))
    
    return groups
```

But the output was incorrect:

```
[[(0, 9)],
 [(3, 6), (3, 8), (3, 9)],
 [(4, 6), (4, 7), (4, 8)],
 [(30, 88), (30, 97)],
 [(90, 40), (90, 41)]]
```

## EDIT

Putting  here my real list, it has a len() of 2067, so if it's better I can put it on a github gist or some kind of pastebin.

```
IN = [(0, 792),(0, 793),(0, 810),(0, 811),(0, 812),(0, 813),(1, 810),(1, 811),(1, 812),(1, 813),(2, 792),(2, 793),(3, 792),(3, 793),(3, 810),(3, 811),(3, 812),(3, 813),(4, 810),(4, 811),(4, 812),(4, 813),(4, 832),(4, 833),(5, 810),(5, 811),(6, 768),(6, 772),(7, 767),(7, 768),(7, 772),(8, 809),(9, 830),(9, 845),(10, 830),(11, 831),(11, 846),(11, 847),(12, 830),(12, 831),(12, 846),(12, 847),(13, 844),(14, 899),(15, 886),(15, 887),(15, 899),(16, 884),(16, 885),(17, 884),(17, 885),(18, 948),(19, 957),(19, 958),(19, 959),(20, 957),(20, 958),(21, 961),(21, 962),(21, 977),(22, 961),(22, 962),(22, 963),(23, 990),(24, 998),(24, 1000),(25, 966),(25, 979),(25, 980),(25, 981),(26, 966),(26, 979),(26, 980),(26, 981),(27, 957),(27, 958),(27, 959),(27, 964),(27, 967),(27, 968),(27, 969),(28, 954),(28, 955),(29, 954),(29, 955),(30, 806),(30, 807),(30, 808),(31, 806),(31, 807),(31, 808),(31, 830),(32, 806),(33, 791),(34, 760),(34, 761),(34, 762),(35, 760),(35, 761),(36, 888),(37, 810),(37, 811),(37, 812),(37, 813),(37, 832),(37, 833),(38, 925),(39, 915),(40, 949),(41, 970),(41, 971),(41, 972),(41, 973),(42, 970),(42, 971),(42, 972),(42, 982),(42, 983),(42, 984),(43, 970),(43, 971),(43, 972),(44, 846),(44, 847),(45, 957),(45, 958),(45, 959),(46, 914),(46, 924),(47, 936),(47, 937),(47, 938),(47, 948),(48, 934),(48, 935),(48, 936),(48, 937),(49, 934),(49, 935),(50, 956),(50, 961),(50, 962),(51, 968),(51, 969),(51, 980),(51, 981),(52, 964),(52, 966),(52, 967),(52, 968),(52, 969),(52, 979),(52, 980),(52, 981),(53, 968),(53, 969),(54, 963),(54, 964),(54, 965),(54, 966),(54, 967),(54, 978),(54, 979),(55, 988),(55, 989),(56, 961),(56, 962),(56, 977),(57, 953),(58, 975),(58, 976),(59, 906),(60, 922),(61, 960),(62, 936),(62, 937),(62, 938),(63, 898),(64, 753),(65, 907),(65, 923),(66, 790),(67, 995),(67, 996),(68, 766),(68, 769),(69, 765),(69, 766),(69, 769),(69, 770),(70, 770),(71, 784),(71, 785),(71, 786),(71, 787),(71, 788),(72, 784),(72, 785),(72, 786),(72, 787),(72, 788),(73, 784),(73, 785),(73, 786),(73, 787),(73, 788),(73, 803),(73, 804),(73, 805),(74, 803),(74, 804),(75, 784),(75, 785),(75, 786),(75, 787),(75, 788),(75, 803),(75, 804),(75, 805),(76, 784),(76, 785),(76, 786),(76, 787),(76, 788),(76, 803),(76, 804),(76, 805),(77, 789),(78, 771),(79, 827),(80, 780),(81, 782),(81, 783),(82, 782),(82, 783),(83, 781),(84, 757),(84, 758),(84, 763),(84, 764),(85, 832),(85, 833),(86, 848),(87, 794),(87, 795),(88, 900),(89, 886),(89, 887),(90, 916),(90, 917),(91, 993),(92, 992),(93, 982),(94, 997),(94, 998),(94, 1000),(95, 987),(96, 921),(97, 781),(97, 782),(97, 783),(97, 802),(98, 864),(99, 896),(99, 897),(100, 895),(100, 896),(100, 897),(101, 843),(101, 863),(102, 843),(103, 803),(103, 804),(103, 805),(103, 828),(103, 829),(104, 1003),(105, 908),(105, 909),(105, 910),(105, 911),(106, 908),(106, 909),(106, 910),(106, 911),(107, 908),(107, 909),(108, 923),(109, 910),(109, 911),(109, 912),(110, 910),(110, 911),(110, 912),(111, 934),(111, 935),(111, 936),(111, 937),(112, 950),(112, 951),(113, 950),(113, 951),(114, 973),(115, 970),(115, 971),(115, 972),(115, 983),(115, 984),(116, 983),(116, 984),(116, 985),(117, 991),(118, 999),(119, 750),(119, 751),(120, 751),(120, 752),(121, 758),(121, 763),(121, 764),(122, 758),(122, 763),(122, 764),(122, 765),(123, 756),(124, 1007),(124, 1008),(125, 1011),(126, 1006),(126, 1007),(126, 1008),(127, 1004),(128, 1009),(129, 975),(129, 976),(130, 965),(130, 978),(131, 1002),(132, 1001),(133, 961),(133, 962),(133, 963),(134, 762),(135, 759),(136, 1010),(137, 913),(137, 914),(137, 924),(138, 600),(138, 601),(138, 602),(139, 600),(139, 601),(139, 602),(140, 584),(140, 585),(140, 586),(140, 587),(141, 619),(141, 620),(141, 630),(142, 656),(143, 669),(143, 676),(144, 668),(144, 669),(144, 676),(145, 685),(146, 666),(146, 667),(146, 674),(146, 675),(147, 666),(147, 667),(148, 684),(148, 695),(149, 685),(149, 686),(149, 688),(149, 689),(149, 696),(150, 696),(151, 676),(151, 679),(152, 676),(153, 636),(154, 656),(155, 650),(156, 670),(158, 680),(158, 690),(158, 691),(159, 622),(159, 623),(160, 622),(160, 623),(161, 608),(161, 619),(161, 620),(162, 619),(162, 620),(163, 565),(163, 570),(163, 571),(163, 582),(163, 584),(163, 585),(163, 586),(164, 570),(165, 613),(165, 615),(166, 599),(166, 616),(167, 591),(167, 599),(168, 612),(168, 613),(168, 614),(168, 615),(169, 610),(169, 611),(170, 737),(170, 738),(171, 683),(172, 609),(172, 621),(173, 555),(173, 563),(173, 564),(173, 565),(173, 566),(173, 567),(173, 571),(173, 572),(174, 565),(174, 566),(174, 571),(174, 572),(174, 584),(174, 585),(174, 586),(174, 587),(175, 565),(175, 571),(175, 584),(175, 585),(175, 586),(176, 582),(176, 584),(176, 585),(176, 586),(177, 561),(178, 641),(178, 642),(178, 643),(179, 638),(179, 639),(179, 640),(179, 641),(179, 642),(179, 643),(180, 638),(180, 639),(180, 640),(180, 641),(180, 642),(180, 643),(181, 632),(182, 638),(182, 639),(182, 640),(183, 638),(183, 639),(183, 640),(184, 638),(184, 639),(184, 640),(184, 641),(184, 642),(184, 643),(185, 548),(185, 549),(185, 550),(186, 548),(187, 544),(187, 545),(187, 548),(188, 549),(188, 550),(189, 543),(189, 544),(189, 545),(190, 532),(191, 531),(192, 587),(192, 588),(192, 598),(193, 587),(193, 588),(194, 609),(194, 621),(195, 597),(196, 568),(197, 592),(198, 575),(198, 590),(198, 591),(199, 546),(200, 547),(200, 554),(200, 556),(201, 552),(201, 553),(202, 612),(202, 613),(202, 614),(202, 615),(203, 590),(203, 591),(204, 624),(205, 575),(205, 590),(206, 651),(207, 637),(208, 680),(209, 687),(209, 690),(210, 631),(211, 523),(211, 533),(212, 520),(212, 521),(212, 522),(212, 523),(213, 515),(213, 516),(213, 520),(213, 522),(214, 558),(215, 517),(215, 518),(215, 520),(215, 521),(215, 522),(216, 517),(216, 518),(217, 517),(217, 518),(217, 521),(218, 517),(218, 518),(218, 519),(219, 573),(219, 574),(220, 564),(220, 566),(220, 567),(220, 572),(220, 573),(221, 530),(221, 531),(222, 562),(223, 512),(224, 648),(224, 649),(225, 648),(225, 649),(226, 648),(226, 649),(227, 656),(228, 676),(229, 695),(230, 703),(231, 695),(231, 699),(232, 686),(232, 688),(232, 689),(232, 696),(233, 686),(233, 687),(233, 688),(233, 689),(234, 547),(234, 554),(234, 556),(235, 554),(235, 555),(235, 563),(236, 564),(236, 566),(236, 567),(236, 572),(236, 573),(237, 589),(238, 556),(238, 557),(239, 634),(239, 635),(240, 634),(240, 635),(241, 667),(241, 668),(242, 542),(243, 608),(243, 619),(243, 620),(244, 582),(244, 583),(245, 681),(245, 682),(246, 610),(246, 611),(247, 834),(247, 835),(247, 836),(247, 837),(247, 838),(248, 834),(248, 835),(248, 836),(249, 834),(249, 835),(249, 836),(250, 834),(250, 835),(250, 836),(250, 837),(250, 838),(251, 837),(251, 838),(251, 849),(252, 868),(252, 889),(252, 890),(253, 866),(253, 869),(253, 870),(253, 890),(254, 849),(254, 850),(254, 851),(255, 839),(255, 840),(256, 775),(256, 797),(256, 798),(256, 816),(256, 817),(256, 818),(256, 819),(257, 775),(257, 797),(257, 798),(257, 816),(257, 817),(257, 818),(257, 819),(258, 817),(258, 818),(258, 819),(259, 817),(259, 818),(259, 819),(260, 852),(260, 853),(260, 872),(261, 852),(261, 853),(261, 871),(261, 872),(262, 902),(263, 891),(263, 901),(263, 902),(264, 854),(264, 855),(264, 856),(265, 854),(265, 856),(267, 822),(268, 800),(268, 817),(268, 818),(268, 819),(268, 820),(268, 821),(269, 852),(269, 853),(269, 872),(270, 933),(270, 947),(271, 944),(271, 945),(271, 946),(272, 944),(272, 945),(272, 946),(273, 932),(273, 944),(273, 945),(273, 946),(274, 939),(274, 940),(274, 941),(274, 942),(274, 943),(275, 939),(275, 940),(275, 941),(276, 866),(276, 868),(276, 869),(276, 889),(277, 866),(277, 868),(277, 869),(277, 889),(278, 865),(278, 866),(278, 867),(278, 868),(278, 869),(278, 889),(279, 839),(279, 849),(279, 850),(279, 851),(280, 814),(280, 815),(280, 837),(280, 838),(281, 775),(281, 798),(281, 799),(281, 800),(281, 817),(281, 818),(281, 819),(281, 820),(281, 821),(282, 776),(283, 777),(283, 778),(283, 779),(283, 801),(284, 777),(284, 778),(285, 779),(285, 801),(286, 903),(286, 919),(287, 947),(287, 952),(288, 933),(288, 947),(289, 932),(290, 926),(290, 927),(290, 928),(290, 929),(291, 926),(291, 928),(292, 879),(292, 880),(292, 894),(293, 875),(293, 877),(293, 878),(293, 879),(293, 880),(293, 893),(293, 894),(294, 879),(294, 880),(295, 858),(295, 859),(295, 879),(295, 880),(295, 881),(295, 882),(296, 875),(296, 878),(296, 879),(296, 880),(297, 857),(297, 879),(297, 880),(298, 974),(299, 841),(300, 874),(300, 875),(300, 876),(300, 877),(300, 878),(300, 893),(301, 857),(302, 859),(302, 881),(302, 882),(303, 892),(304, 857),(304, 858),(304, 859),(304, 879),(304, 880),(304, 881),(304, 882),(305, 918),(305, 927),(305, 929),(305, 930),(306, 903),(307, 873),(308, 774),(308, 775),(308, 798),(309, 754),(309, 755),(310, 986),(311, 930),(311, 931),(312, 918),(313, 814),(313, 815),(314, 839),(314, 849),(314, 850),(314, 851),(315, 773),(315, 796),(316, 773),(317, 823),(317, 824),(317, 825),(317, 826),(318, 919),(318, 920),(319, 1005),(320, 994),(321, 939),(321, 940),(321, 941),(321, 942),(321, 943),(322, 904),(322, 905),(323, 860),(323, 862),(324, 860),(324, 861),(324, 862),(325, 883),(326, 842),(327, 890),(327, 891),(327, 901),(328, 800),(328, 820),(328, 821),(329, 428),(329, 429),(329, 430),(330, 380),(331, 374),(331, 375),(332, 374),(332, 375),(333, 378),(333, 379),(334, 378),(334, 379),(335, 373),(336, 362),(337, 362),(337, 366),(338, 366),(338, 371),(339, 365),(340, 336),(341, 345),(341, 346),(342, 420),(343, 413),(343, 414),(344, 402),(344, 403),(345, 402),(345, 403),(346, 400),(347, 401),(348, 423),(348, 426),(349, 425),(350, 418),(350, 419),(350, 422),(351, 419),(351, 422),(352, 350),(352, 351),(353, 350),(353, 351),(354, 356),(355, 355),(356, 355),(357, 341),(357, 342),(358, 341),(358, 342),(359, 332),(360, 337),(360, 338),(360, 339),(360, 340),(361, 320),(361, 321),(362, 320),(362, 321),(363, 294),(363, 295),(364, 294),(364, 295),(365, 327),(366, 367),(367, 406),(367, 407),(368, 405),(368, 406),(368, 407),(369, 191),(370, 176),(371, 90),(372, 34),(373, 74),(373, 75),(374, 74),(374, 75),(375, 164),(376, 309),(377, 333),(378, 331),(380, 385),(380, 386),(381, 385),(381, 386),(382, 393),(383, 372),(384, 319),(385, 311),(386, 429),(386, 430),(387, 438),(387, 439),(387, 440),(387, 441),(387, 443),(387, 444),(387, 445),(387, 452),(387, 453),(387, 454),(387, 455),(388, 452),(388, 453),(388, 454),(388, 455),(388, 460),(388, 461),(388, 462),(389, 441),(389, 442),(389, 443),(389, 444),(389, 445),(389, 446),(389, 454),(389, 455),(390, 461),(390, 462),(391, 461),(391, 462),(391, 474),(392, 437),(392, 438),(392, 439),(392, 440),(393, 426),(393, 438),(393, 439),(393, 440),(394, 426),(394, 427),(395, 441),(395, 442),(395, 443),(395, 444),(395, 445),(395, 446),(396, 441),(396, 443),(396, 444),(396, 445),(397, 428),(397, 442),(397, 446),(398, 461),(398, 462),(399, 452),(399, 453),(399, 460),(400, 450),(400, 451),(401, 450),(401, 451),(402, 437),(402, 438),(402, 439),(402, 440),(403, 438),(403, 439),(403, 440),(403, 452),(403, 453),(404, 427),(404, 441),(404, 443),(404, 444),(404, 445),(405, 441),(405, 442),(405, 443),(405, 444),(405, 445),(405, 446),(405, 454),(405, 455),(406, 478),(406, 479),(406, 485),(406, 487),(407, 479),(407, 487),(408, 485),(408, 497),(409, 484),(409, 486),(410, 484),(410, 485),(410, 486),(411, 473),(412, 499),(413, 495),(413, 496),(413, 499),(414, 501),(414, 502),(414, 503),(415, 502),(415, 503),(416, 464),(416, 465),(417, 464),(417, 465),(418, 489),(419, 488),(420, 559),(421, 504),(422, 704),(422, 705),(423, 483),(424, 438),(424, 439),(424, 440),(424, 441),(424, 443),(424, 444),(424, 445),(424, 452),(424, 453),(424, 454),(424, 455),(425, 456),(426, 463),(427, 493),(428, 507),(428, 508),(428, 509),(428, 510),(429, 508),(429, 509),(429, 510),(430, 510),(431, 644),(431, 645),(432, 633),(433, 644),(433, 645),(434, 660),(435, 747),(435, 748),(435, 749),(436, 747),(436, 748),(436, 749),(437, 706),(437, 707),(438, 701),(439, 524),(440, 500),(441, 457),(442, 466),(442, 467),(443, 498),(444, 482),(444, 491),(444, 492),(445, 480),(445, 481),(445, 482),(445, 491),(446, 490),(447, 480),(447, 481),(448, 505),(448, 506),(449, 700),(450, 672),(451, 658),(451, 659),(451, 671),(452, 658),(452, 659),(452, 671),(453, 625),(453, 626),(454, 657),(455, 692),(456, 745),(456, 746),(457, 739),(459, 7),(459, 8),(459, 9),(459, 11),(459, 12),(460, 38),(460, 49),(461, 36),(461, 37),(462, 9),(462, 10),(462, 11),(462, 12),(462, 13),(463, 10),(463, 13),(464, 39),(465, 50),(466, 9),(466, 11),(466, 12),(467, 10),(467, 13),(468, 38),(469, 7),(469, 8),(469, 9),(469, 11),(469, 12),(472, 26),(474, 35),(474, 36),(474, 37),(475, 252),(475, 267),(476, 298),(477, 296),(477, 297),(478, 296),(478, 297),(479, 275),(479, 276),(479, 277),(480, 266),(480, 267),(480, 276),(480, 277),(480, 278),(481, 253),(481, 254),(482, 288),(482, 289),(482, 290),(483, 269),(483, 279),(483, 288),(483, 289),(483, 290),(484, 288),(484, 290),(485, 251),(485, 252),(485, 266),(485, 267),(486, 276),(486, 277),(487, 266),(487, 267),(488, 225),(488, 226),(488, 227),(488, 228),(489, 251),(489, 252),(490, 229),(490, 252),(490, 253),(491, 227),(491, 265),(492, 204),(492, 205),(492, 206),(492, 207),(493, 120),(493, 121),(494, 120),(494, 121),(495, 61),(496, 126),(496, 127),(497, 124),(497, 152),(498, 123),(498, 124),(498, 152),(499, 105),(499, 106),(499, 107),(499, 122),(500, 105),(500, 106),(500, 107),(500, 122),(501, 105),(501, 106),(501, 107),(501, 122),(502, 14),(503, 60),(504, 230),(505, 270),(505, 271),(506, 268),(506, 269),(506, 279),(507, 178),(508, 125),(509, 383),(510, 153),(511, 128),(511, 129),(512, 128),(512, 129),(513, 128),(513, 129),(513, 154),(514, 108),(515, 208),(516, 177),(517, 347),(518, 286),(519, 215),(520, 192),(521, 377),(522, 376),(523, 390),(524, 399),(525, 404),(526, 396),(526, 397),(527, 396),(527, 397),(527, 398),(528, 395),(529, 387),(529, 388),(530, 387),(530, 388),(530, 389),(531, 416),(531, 417),(532, 335),(533, 334),(534, 322),(535, 424),(536, 408),(536, 409),(537, 408),(538, 381),(538, 382),(539, 415),(540, 348),(540, 349),(541, 330),(542, 421),(543, 391),(543, 392),(544, 394),(545, 10),(545, 13),(546, 10),(546, 13),(547, 358),(548, 357),(549, 343),(550, 287),(551, 150),(551, 151),(552, 203),(553, 328),(553, 329),(554, 7),(554, 8),(554, 9),(554, 11),(554, 12),(555, 9),(555, 11),(555, 12),(556, 6),(556, 7),(556, 8),(557, 91),(558, 361),(559, 363),(560, 360),(561, 165),(562, 2),(563, 2),(564, 4),(564, 5),(565, 3),(566, 364),(567, 410),(568, 359),(569, 352),(570, 352),(570, 353),(570, 354),(571, 353),(571, 354),(572, 160),(573, 138),(573, 139),(573, 140),(573, 141),(574, 135),(574, 136),(574, 137),(574, 138),(574, 139),(574, 159),(574, 160),(575, 111),(575, 135),(575, 136),(575, 137),(575, 138),(575, 139),(576, 140),(576, 141),(576, 161),(577, 161),(577, 162),(578, 170),(578, 171),(579, 161),(579, 162),(579, 168),(579, 169),(579, 170),(579, 171),(580, 198),(580, 199),(580, 200),(580, 211),(581, 184),(581, 198),(581, 199),(581, 200),(582, 184),(582, 198),(582, 199),(582, 200),(583, 210),(583, 211),(584, 232),(584, 233),(585, 167),(585, 181),(586, 181),(586, 195),(586, 196),(587, 209),(588, 193),(588, 194),(589, 180),(589, 193),(589, 194),(590, 216),(591, 168),(591, 169),(591, 185),(592, 160),(592, 161),(592, 168),(592, 169),(593, 112),(593, 113),(594, 112),(594, 113),(595, 133),(595, 157),(595, 158),(596, 132),(596, 133),(596, 134),(596, 157),(596, 158),(597, 132),(597, 133),(597, 134),(597, 157),(597, 158),(598, 132),(598, 134),(599, 133),(599, 157),(599, 158),(600, 133),(600, 156),(600, 157),(600, 158),(600, 167),(601, 182),(601, 183),(602, 99),(602, 111),(602, 112),(602, 113),(603, 111),(603, 138),(603, 139),(604, 77),(605, 99),(605, 111),(605, 112),(605, 113),(606, 232),(607, 210),(608, 132),(608, 133),(608, 134),(608, 135),(608, 136),(608, 137),(608, 157),(608, 158),(608, 159),(609, 132),(609, 133),(609, 134),(609, 135),(609, 136),(609, 137),(609, 157),(609, 158),(609, 159),(610, 109),(610, 130),(611, 109),(612, 142),(612, 143),(612, 144),(613, 111),(613, 112),(613, 113),(613, 138),(613, 139),(613, 140),(613, 141),(614, 182),(614, 183),(614, 184),(614, 197),(614, 198),(614, 199),(614, 200),(615, 161),(615, 162),(615, 168),(615, 169),(615, 170),(615, 171),(616, 234),(617, 218),(617, 219),(618, 209),(618, 217),(618, 218),(618, 219),(619, 231),(620, 143),(620, 144),(620, 145),(620, 163),(621, 162),(622, 196),(622, 197),(623, 197),(623, 198),(623, 199),(623, 200),(624, 218),(624, 219),(625, 195),(626, 193),(626, 194),(626, 195),(626, 209),(627, 131),(627, 132),(627, 134),(628, 156),(628, 167),(629, 179),(630, 62),(630, 63),(631, 62),(631, 63),(632, 166),(633, 155),(634, 303),(634, 304),(635, 301),(636, 411),(636, 412),(637, 255),(637, 257),(637, 258),(638, 260),(638, 272),(639, 255),(639, 256),(639, 257),(639, 258),(639, 259),(640, 255),(640, 256),(640, 257),(640, 258),(640, 259),(640, 260),(640, 272),(641, 255),(641, 256),(641, 257),(641, 258),(641, 259),(641, 260),(641, 272),(642, 280),(643, 292),(644, 291),(645, 78),(646, 92),(646, 93),(647, 236),(648, 344),(649, 312),(650, 211),(651, 220),(652, 235),(653, 168),(653, 169),(653, 170),(653, 171),(653, 185),(654, 172),(655, 145),(655, 163),(656, 143),(656, 144),(656, 145),(657, 143),(657, 144),(658, 384),(659, 100),(659, 101),(660, 100),(660, 101),(661, 15),(662, 323),(663, 299),(663, 300),(664, 76),(665, 92),(665, 93),(666, 368),(667, 110),(667, 131),(668, 114),(669, 102),(669, 114),(670, 94),(671, 186),(672, 237),(672, 238),(672, 239),(672, 240),(673, 237),(673, 238),(673, 239),(673, 240),(674, 237),(674, 238),(674, 239),(674, 240),(675, 237),(675, 238),(675, 239),(675, 240),(676, 79),(676, 80),(677, 0),(677, 27),(678, 64),(679, 51),(680, 212),(680, 221),(681, 241),(681, 242),(681, 262),(682, 305),(683, 307),(683, 308),(684, 173),(684, 174),(685, 173),(685, 174),(687, 1),(688, 1),(689, 52),(690, 66),(690, 80),(691, 146),(691, 147),(692, 115),(693, 324),(693, 325),(693, 326),(694, 283),(695, 247),(695, 248),(696, 247),(697, 274),(697, 284),(698, 263),(698, 273),(699, 263),(700, 264),(701, 213),(701, 224),(702, 213),(702, 224),(703, 213),(703, 214),(704, 188),(705, 175),(705, 188),(705, 189),(705, 190),(706, 175),(706, 188),(706, 189),(706, 190),(707, 175),(707, 189),(707, 190),(708, 104),(709, 87),(710, 55),(710, 56),(710, 57),(711, 54),(711, 55),(711, 56),(711, 57),(712, 54),(712, 55),(712, 56),(712, 57),(713, 96),(714, 84),(714, 85),(714, 86),(715, 84),(715, 85),(715, 95),(716, 119),(717, 82),(717, 83),(717, 84),(717, 85),(717, 95),(718, 82),(719, 103),(720, 31),(720, 43),(721, 31),(721, 43),(722, 17),(722, 18),(723, 17),(723, 18),(724, 82),(724, 84),(724, 85),(725, 84),(725, 85),(725, 86),(726, 19),(726, 20),(726, 21),(726, 22),(727, 19),(727, 20),(727, 21),(727, 22),(728, 72),(729, 45),(730, 70),(730, 71),(731, 47),(731, 48),(732, 47),(732, 48),(733, 24),(733, 25),(735, 19),(735, 21),(735, 32),(738, 20),(738, 22),(738, 23),(739, 44),(740, 81),(741, 16),(742, 97),(742, 98),(743, 97),(743, 98),(744, 89),(745, 73),(746, 46),(747, 20),(747, 22),(747, 23),(747, 33),(748, 24),(748, 25),(749, 249),(749, 250),(750, 274),(752, 41),(753, 40),(753, 41),(754, 67),(754, 68),(754, 69),(755, 58),(756, 149),(757, 246),(758, 306),(759, 187),(760, 16),(763, 222),(763, 223),(763, 243),(764, 242),(764, 262),(765, 242),(765, 262),(766, 221),(767, 65),(767, 66),(767, 67),(767, 68),(768, 69),(769, 325),(769, 326),(770, 0),(771, 83),(771, 95),(772, 19),(772, 21),(772, 32),(774, 42),(775, 29),(776, 116),(776, 117),(777, 118),(777, 148),(778, 53),(779, 47),(779, 48),(779, 59),(780, 88),(781, 55),(781, 56),(781, 57),(782, 315),(782, 316),(782, 317),(782, 318),(783, 30),(784, 369),(784, 370),(785, 28),(786, 245),(787, 189),(787, 190),(787, 202),(788, 201),(789, 310),(790, 302),(791, 118),(792, 314),(793, 223),(793, 243),(793, 244),(794, 261),(795, 293),(796, 313),(797, 281),(797, 282),(798, 285),(799, 693),(800, 673),(801, 596),(802, 728),(802, 741),(802, 742),(802, 743),(802, 744),(803, 742),(803, 743),(803, 744),(804, 742),(804, 743),(804, 744),(805, 726),(805, 727),(806, 726),(806, 727),(806, 728),(807, 728),(807, 741),(808, 718),(809, 718),(809, 725),(810, 702),(811, 735),(812, 723),(812, 724),(813, 740),(814, 722),(815, 736),(816, 708),(816, 709),(816, 710),(817, 710),(817, 718),(818, 694),(819, 723),(819, 724),(820, 734),(821, 528),(822, 529),(823, 511),(824, 476),(825, 477),(826, 494),(827, 459),(827, 468),(827, 469),(827, 470),(827, 471),(827, 472),(828, 469),(828, 470),(828, 471),(828, 472),(829, 469),(829, 470),(829, 471),(829, 472),(830, 469),(830, 470),(830, 471),(830, 472),(831, 435),(831, 436),(832, 435),(832, 436),(832, 448),(832, 449),(833, 447),(833, 448),(833, 449),(834, 435),(834, 436),(834, 447),(834, 448),(834, 449),(835, 448),(835, 449),(836, 577),(836, 579),(836, 580),(836, 581),(836, 595),(837, 577),(837, 579),(837, 580),(837, 581),(837, 595),(838, 576),(838, 577),(838, 578),(838, 579),(838, 580),(838, 581),(838, 595),(839, 712),(839, 713),(839, 714),(839, 716),(840, 712),(840, 713),(840, 714),(840, 715),(840, 716),(840, 719),(840, 720),(841, 713),(841, 714),(841, 715),(841, 716),(841, 720),(842, 712),(842, 713),(842, 714),(842, 716),(843, 717),(844, 721),(845, 719),(845, 732),(845, 733),(846, 732),(846, 733),(847, 731),(848, 711),(849, 729),(849, 730),(850, 697),(850, 698),(851, 697),(851, 698),(852, 697),(852, 698),(853, 605),(853, 617),(853, 618),(854, 605),(854, 617),(854, 618),(855, 604),(855, 605),(855, 606),(855, 607),(855, 617),(855, 618),(856, 593),(856, 594),(857, 593),(857, 594),(858, 604),(858, 606),(858, 607),(859, 606),(859, 607),(860, 603),(860, 604),(861, 569),(862, 560),(863, 551),(864, 525),(864, 526),(864, 527),(865, 525),(865, 526),(865, 527),(866, 534),(866, 538),(867, 534),(867, 535),(867, 536),(867, 537),(867, 538),(867, 539),(867, 541),(868, 535),(868, 539),(868, 540),(868, 541),(869, 535),(869, 539),(869, 541),(870, 513),(871, 513),(871, 514),(872, 664),(872, 665),(873, 664),(873, 665),(874, 654),(874, 655),(875, 677),(875, 678),(876, 653),(877, 652),(878, 647),(879, 628),(879, 629),(880, 627),(880, 628),(880, 629),(881, 646),(882, 661),(882, 662),(882, 663),(883, 661),(883, 662),(883, 663),(884, 431),(884, 433),(885, 431),(885, 432),(886, 434),(887, 458),(887, 459),(887, 468),(888, 459),(888, 468),(888, 475)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I figured it out. If I treat the connections kind of a graph it's possible to route all links and group them.

```
import networkx as nx

def group_tuples(tuples):
    '''Receives a list of bidimensional tuples
    and group it by direct or indirect connection.
    The output is a list which elements are sublists
    containing connected tuples (groups)'''
    
    # Create a graph
    graph = nx.Graph()

    # Add tuples as nodes to the graph
    graph.add_nodes_from(tuples)

    # Add edges based on the connection criteria
    for tuple1 in tuples:
        for tuple2 in tuples:
            if tuple1 != tuple2:
                x1, y1 = tuple1
                x2, y2 = tuple2

                # Check if there is a direct or indirect connection
                if x1 == x2 or y1 == y2:
                    graph.add_edge(tuple1, tuple2)

    # Extract the connected components from the graph
    connected_components = list(nx.connected_components(graph))

    # Convert connected components to groups
    groups = [list(component) for component in connected_components]

    return groups
```

## EDIT:

removed redundancy from the code, as the comment by @win

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the list of tuples to a set of tuples as a pool, pop a tuple from the pool to form a new group as a set, and find all tuples in the pool that intersect with the group while expanding the group with the vertices in the tuple, until there is no more candidate tuple in pool that can intersect with the group, at which point pop a new tuple from the pool to form a new group to repeat the process. Use a dict to map each group to a list of belonging tuples. Since sets are not hashable, use the identities of the groups as keys instead. The output would be the list values of the mapping:

```
def group_tuples(tuples):
    pool = set(tuples)
    groups = []
    mapping = {}
    while pool:
        edge = pool.pop()
        group = set(edge)
        groups.append(group) # add the group to a list so its id won't get reused
        group_id = id(group)
        mapping[group_id] = [edge]
        while True:
            for candidate in pool:
                if group.intersection(candidate):
                    group.update(candidate)
                    pool.remove(candidate)
                    mapping[group_id].append(candidate)
                    break
            else:
                break
    return list(mapping.values())
```

so that:

```
IN = [(3, 9), (4, 6), (0, 9), (3, 8), (4, 8), (4, 7), (3, 6), (30, 97), (30, 88), (90, 40),]
print(group_tuples(IN))
```

outputs:

```
[[(90, 40)], [(3, 8), (3, 9), (0, 9), (4, 8), (4, 6), (3, 6), (4, 7)], [(30, 88), (30, 97)]]
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/TemptingFixedWeblogsoftware

Comment: @blhsing The issue with your code is that it considers (1, 2) and (3, 1) to be neighbors, but that is not correct per the problem description